# Question about "&" in Groovy

Tags: groovy

like this:
**Groovy:**

```
map = ['a':1,'b':2]
doubler = this.&doubleMethod
map.each(doubler)
println map
```

What's the "&" used for here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the `.&` operator is a *method reference*, i.e. it turns the indicated method into a closure so that it can be passed to other methods that want a closure as an argument.